# Pandas adding a row from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and Pandas and I'm working on a sample project. As part of that I'm reading each row in a dataframe and determining which of 3 dataframes it should go into. I'm getting inconsistent results on adding the row. Sometimes it adds the row, other times not. I've tried several different ways to add the row, all with limited success. A section of my code is below:

```
#split seed into categories
dfSeedSetosa = dfSeed[dfSeed['Class'] == 'Iris-setosa']
dfSeedVirginica = dfSeed[dfSeed['Class'] == 'Iris-virginica']
dfSeedVersicolor = dfSeed[dfSeed['Class'] == 'Iris-versicolor']

dfSeedSetosa.is_copy = False
dfSeedVirginica.is_copy = False
dfSeedVersicolor.is_copy = False

#calc beginning averages
CalcSetosa()
CalcVirginica()
CalcVersicolor()

#remove seed values from body
dfBody = df[~df.isin(dfSeed)].dropna()

#cycle through the body rows individually, find closest match, add record to appropriate seed, recalc averages
for index, row in dfBody.iterrows():
    numSet = abs(numAvgSetSepLen-row['SepalLen'])+abs(numAvgSetSepWid-row['SepalWid'])+abs(numAvgSetPetLen-row['PetalLen'])+abs(numAvgSetPetWid-row['PetalWid'])+abs(numAvgSetSepRat-row['SepalRat'])+abs(numAvgSetPetRat-row['PetalRat'])
    numVer = abs(numAvgVerSepLen-row['SepalLen'])+abs(numAvgVerSepWid-row['SepalWid'])+abs(numAvgVerPetLen-row['PetalLen'])+abs(numAvgVerPetWid-row['PetalWid'])+abs(numAvgVerSepRat-row['SepalRat'])+abs(numAvgVerPetRat-row['PetalRat'])
    numVir = abs(numAvgVirSepLen-row['SepalLen'])+abs(numAvgVirSepWid-row['SepalWid'])+abs(numAvgVirPetLen-row['PetalLen'])+abs(numAvgVirPetWid-row['PetalWid'])+abs(numAvgVirSepRat-row['SepalRat'])+abs(numAvgVirPetRat-row['PetalRat'])

    if numSet < numVer and numSet < numVir:
        dfSeedSetosa.loc[len(dfSeedSetosa)] = row
        #dfSeedSetosa.append(row, ignore_index=True)
        #dfSeedSetosa.ix[len(dfSeedSetosa.index)] = row
        CalcSetosa()

    elif numVer < numSet and numVer < numVir:
        dfSeedVersicolor.loc[len(dfSeedVersicolor)] = row
        #dfSeedVersicolor.append(row, ignore_index=True)
        #dfSeedVersicolor.ix[len(dfSeedVersicolor.index)] = row
        CalcVersicolor()

    else:
        dfSeedVirginica.loc[len(dfSeedVirginica)] = row
        #dfSeedVirginica.append(row,ignore_index=True)
        #dfSeedVirginica.ix[len(dfSeedVirginica.index)] = row
        CalcVirginica()
```

Comment: Interesting dataset as it looks much like the [iris dataset](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/iris.html) which comes built-in to R, the other open-source programming language used in data analytics.

Comment: Can you describe the rules of placing the rows in others dfs? You don't give an explanation and code is not intuitive. We may need to see some data. What is in df vs dfSeed?

Comment: This does use the iris dataset. I've added 2 columns, one for Sepal ratio (SepalRat) and another for Petal ratio (PetalRat). I take a number of records from the dataset as a "seed" set and organize them by their names so I know which ones belong to the correct categories. I then calculate averages for each one and then cycle through the remaining records to see which it is most similar to. After adding it to the correct dataframe by classification I then recalculate the averages.

Comment: *I'm getting inconsistent results on adding the row. Sometimes it adds the row, other times not.*...we need more specifics. You mean results change with each run of same code and data? Do note: your matching logic is not mutually exclusive as the last else is catchall and will take if first two conditions do not meet including numSet == numVer == numVir or any combination of equals/large/shorter.

Comment: The issue I'm trying to resolve is that on the lines where it is adding the row to any of the dataframes (dfSeedSetosa / dfSeedVersicolor / dfSeedVirginica) sometimes it will add the row and other times it won't. I have been unable to detect a pattern as to why. I have looped through the row as it runs and sometimes the index value for that dataframe has increased and sometimes it doesn't. the issue with the else clause was more intended as a catch all. I suspect it will give me some extraneous results but it is currently a secondary issue.

Comment: You repeated your unclear, unspecific post. Again, if you run same exact code a second time with same exact data are different rows producing? I see no randomization here so can't see how *sometimes* different results appear.